# Returnin text() from a td tag with the class name as 'tdlrow'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table

I am trying to code a script that returns all the text in a TD tag cannot show you full code, but I am  using

`instances = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'tblrow')]")`

to identify the "rows" and then need to return the text located in

`<td align="left" I need this, And this <\td>`

I have also identified the main body that the table is located in using .find_element_by_xpath. Every time I try to

`print(instances.text())`

I get a unicode error I have tried

`print(instances.text().decode("utf-8", "strict")`

to no succsess any questions please ask.

Comment: What unicode error do you exactly see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple approaches to address the `unicode` related error while printing to the console as follows:

- In the first approach you can use `encode('utf-8')` as follows:

  ```
  print(instances.text.encode('utf-8'))
  ```
- In the second approach you can append the following line at the top of your python file:

  ```
  # -*- coding: utf­-8 ­-*-
  ```

Comment: When I use print(instances.text.encode('utf-8')) it comes as blank I think this is because there is no text to return

Comment: @GeorgeBurns What happened when you used `print(instances.text())`?

Comment: So this answer solved the `unicode error` you were facing. Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?

Comment: Yes, it fixed the Unicode error thank you. I think because the table is dynamic there technically isn't that object anymore that is why it is printing blank I need a way to search for how many objects in the dynamic table that have the  <td> tag then decode the text that is held in each individual tag then print.