# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, syntax-error, python-unicode, unicode-escapes

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User\Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options) 
sleep(1)
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
```

I'm not sure what im doing wrong.

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User\Data")
^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-17: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

if you can please help me i would appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User\Data") 
^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-17: truncated \UXXXXXXXX
```

...implies that there is a [decoding](/questions/tagged/decoding) error in the line.

---

Ideally you need to replace the line:

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User\Data")
```

With either of the following lines:

- Using *raw* prefix i.e. **`r`** and *single quotes* (i.e. `'...'`):

  ```
  options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User\Data')
  ```
- Using *double quotes* (i.e. `"..."`) and escaping backslash character (i.e. `\`):

  ```
  options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User\\Data")
  ```
- Using *double quotes* (i.e. `"..."`) and forwardslash character (i.e. `/`):

  ```
  options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User/Data")
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37400974/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-in-position-2-3-trunca/52935424#52935424)
- [Returnin text() from a td tag with the class name as 'tdlrow'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63458006/returnin-text-from-a-td-tag-with-the-class-name-as-tdlrow/63458422#63458422)

Answer (score 0):

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
#path to your browser
options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
#path to the binary files
chrome_driver_binary = r"/Users/name/Downloads/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, options=options)
driver.get(https://www.web.whatsapp.com)
``
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can give you some ideas. Maybe it will help you. I would suggest to save the session by adding to chrome a start-option. For this you will need to add an option like --user-data-dir 
You can use code from a place like this. Here you will find everything you need!
-Whatsapp with Selenium in Python: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whatsapp-using-python/.
Before running your code close chrome, or else Selenium is going to reuse the browerser's current instance and you will not be able to run the option --user-data-dir . I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Place the chromedriver in the C: directory like so:
[image]

Change the following line of code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
```

Or

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\FOLDER\chromedriver.exe')
```

If you want the chromedriver to load from a specify file path.