# Using Selenium to retrieve results results from this site involving radio buttons and text boxes

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I was trying to retrieve information using the Selenium library in Python, from [here](https://tuludictionary.in/dictionary/cgi-bin/web/frame.html).

This is my code, I tried accessing the elements using their XPATHs.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open the webpage
driver.get("https://tuludictionary.in/dictionary/cgi-bin/web/frame.html")

# Select the 'Tulu' radio button
tulu_radio = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/form/input[1]")
tulu_radio.click()

# Select the 'Anywhere' radio button
anywhere_radio = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/form/input[6]")
anywhere_radio.click()

# Input "AA" in the text box
search_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[1]")
search_box.send_keys("AA")

# Click on the search button
search_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[2]")
search_button.click()

# Check and process search results
output_area = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td")
output_text = output_area.text.strip()

# Wait for the results to load
try:
    if output_text != "No results found":
        # Extract and print the text part of the links
        # Wait for the list of links to be displayed
        link_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td"))
        )
        if len(link_elements) > 0:
            # Get the text of the links
            links_text = [link.text for link in link_elements]
            print("List of links:")
            for link_text in links_text:
                print(link_text)
            
            # Click on the fourth link
            fourth_link = link_elements[3]
            fourth_link.click()
    else:
        print("NULL")
        result = None
except:
    # Failed to retrieve results
    print("Failed to retrieve results")
    result = None

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

I tried doing a few things, first clicking on the **'Tulu'**, and **'Anywhere'** or **'Starting with'** radio buttons. Then passing the text in the textbox, say **'AA', 'JK'**, and post-clicking the search button, checking whether **'No results found'** is displayed on the output area. If yes, NULL is returned, else I return the entire text of the output area (which has multiple links). I also tried clicking on one of the links, say the fourth one.

The code didn't seem to work, and the web driver closed abruptly with the following error.

```
  File "C:\Users\chakr\AppData\Local\Temp\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 13, in <module>
    tulu_radio = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/form/input[1]")
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 740, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/form/input[1]"}
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.135); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00F5A813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x00EEC4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00DF5358]
    (No symbol) [0x00E209A5]
    (No symbol) [0x00E20B3B]
    (No symbol) [0x00E4E232]
    (No symbol) [0x00E3A784]
    (No symbol) [0x00E4C922]
    (No symbol) [0x00E3A536]
    (No symbol) [0x00E182DC]
    (No symbol) [0x00E193DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x011BAABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x011FA78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x011F456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00FE51E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x00EF5F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x00EF2328]
    (No symbol) [0x00EF240B]
    (No symbol) [0x00EE4FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x753C7D59+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x7725B74B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x7725B6CF+191]
```

Could someone point out what is wrong with the code and what should be changed?

Comment: _I tried doing a few things_: What are the manual steps you are trying to automate?

Comment: @undetected_selenium Basically, 1. opening the webpage, 2. selecting the Tulu and Anywhere radio buttons, 3. passing strings to the text box and clicking on search, 4. returning null if no results appear 5. else returning the text of all the results (links) 6. Finally, selecting a desired link, say, the fourth link in the list of links that appeared.

Comment: _first clicking on the 'Tulu', and 'Anywhere' or 'Starting with' radio buttons_: You already got a well tested and working [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563507/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `FRAME` which is wrapping all the desired elements, you need to switch into it first and then perform actions like clicking on the radio buttons.

[image]

**Code to switch into the FRAME:**

```
# Open the webpage
driver.get("https://tuludictionary.in/dictionary/cgi-bin/web/frame.html")

# switch into the frame
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "search")))

# Select the 'Tulu' radio button
tulu_radio = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/form/input[1]")
tulu_radio.click()
```

### UPDATE:

 Below is the complete working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open the webpage
driver.get("https://tuludictionary.in/dictionary/cgi-bin/web/frame.html")
driver.maximize_window()

# switch into the frame
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "search")))

# Select the 'Tulu' radio button
tulu_radio = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/form/input[1]")
tulu_radio.click()

# Select the 'Anywhere' radio button
anywhere_radio = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/form/input[6]")
anywhere_radio.click()

# Input "AA" in the text box
search_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[1]")
search_box.send_keys("AA")

# Click on the search button
search_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[2]")
search_button.click()

# switch back to main content and switch into 'resultside' FRAME
driver.switch_to.default_content()
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "resultside")))

# Check and process search results
output_area = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td")
output_text = output_area.text.strip()

# Wait for the results to load
try:
    if output_text != "No results found":
        # Extract and print the text part of the links
        # Wait for the list of links to be displayed
        link_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/a"))
        )
        if len(link_elements) > 0:
            # Get the text of the links
            print("List of links:")
            for link_text in link_elements:
                print(link_text.text)

            # Click on the fourth link
            fourth_link = link_elements[3]
            fourth_link.click()
    else:
        print("NULL")
        result = None
except:
    # Failed to retrieve results
    print("Failed to retrieve results")
    result = None

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

### Console Output:

```
List of links:
-ಅoಬರಾ -ụmbaraa
-ಅoಬೆರಾ -ụmberaa
-ಅಪಾ -apaa
-ಅರೆಗಾತ್ರ -aregaatra
-ಅರೆಗಾಸ್ರ -aregaasra
-ಆ -aa
-ಆ -aa
-ಆ -aa
-ಆ -aa
-ಆ -aa
-ಆ -aa
-ಆ -aa
-ಆಂಡ -aaṇḍa
-ಆಂತೆ -aantϵ
-ಆಂದೆ -aandϵ
-ಆಂದ್ -aandụ
-ಆಟ -aaṭa
-ಆಟ -aaṭa
-ಆಟೊ -aaṭo
-ಆಡ -aaḍa
-ಆಡಿ -aaḍi
-ಆಣ -aaṇa
-ಆಣ -aaṇa
-ಆಣಿ -aaṇi
-ಆತೆಕೆ -aateke
-ಆತೆಗೆ -aatege
-ಆತ್ -aatụ
-ಆತ್ -aatụ
-ಆತ್ರ -aatra
-ಆದಿಗೆ -aadigϵ
-ಆದ್ -aadụ
-ಆದ್ -aadụ
-ಆನ -aana
-ಆನ -aana
-ಆನಿ -aani
-ಆಯ್ -aayụ
-ಆರ -aara
-ಆರ -aara
-ಆರ -aara
-ಆರ್ -aarụ
-ಆಲ್ -aalụ
-ಆಳ -aaḷa
-ಆಳ್ -aaḷụ
-ಆಳ್ -aaḷụ
-ಆವ -aava
-ಆವ -aava
-ಆವನೆ -aavane
-ಆವರ -aavara
-ಆವರೊ -aavaro
-ಆವಾ -aavaa
-ಆವು -aavu
-ಆವು -aavu
-ಆವು -aavu
-ಆವ್ -aavụ
-ಆಸ್ರ -aasra
-ಇರ್ಸಾರ -irụsaara
-ಉಂಬರಾ -umbaraa
-ಎಟ್ಟಾ -eṭṭaa
-ಎರಾ -eraa
-ಒಂಟಾ -oṇṭaa
-ಒಂತವಾ -ontavaa
-ಒಲಿಯಾ -oliyaa
-ಕಾ -kaa
-ಕಾರ -kaara
-ಕಾರ -kaara
-ಕ್ಣಾ -kụṇaa
-ಗಾರೆ -gaare
-ಗಾರ್ -gaarụ
-ಜಾರ್ -jaarụ
-ಟಾವ -ṭaava
-ಟ್ಪಾ -ṭụpaa
-ಟ್ಪ್ಪಾ -ṭụppaa
-ತವಾ -tavaa
-ತಾ ತೊ -taa to
-ತಾವ -taava
-ತಿಮಾರ್ -timaarụ
-ದಾರೆ -daare
-ದಾರ್ -daarụ
-ನಾ -naa
-ನಾ -naa
-ಪಾ -paa
-ಪಾಯ -paaya
-ಪಾಯಿ -paayi
-ಪುಟ್ನಾಯೆ -puṭnaaye
-ಪ್ಪಾಯಿ -ppaayi
-ಮಾತಿಗ -maatiga
-ಮಾರ್ -maarụ
-ಮಾರ್ಕುಳು -maarkuḷu
-ಮಾರ್ಗ -maarga
-ಮಾಸ್ರ -maasra
-ಮಾಸ್ರಿ -maasri
-ರಾಕೆ -raakϵ
-ವಾಶಿ -vaaśi
-ವಾಸಿ -vaasi
-ಷ್ಟ್ಪಾ -ṣṭụpaa
-ಸಾರ -saara
-ಸಾರಿ -saari
-ಸೊಬಾನೆ -sobaanϵ
.( poḍattarϵmaalϵ
.. kebtaṇḍegụ haakuni
ಅಡ ಕಾರ್ ụḍa kaarụ
ಅಡೆಯಾಡ್ ụḍeyaaḍụ
ಅದನಾ ụdanaa
ಅದಾಪು ụdaapu
ಅಪಚಾರಿಪು ụpacaaripu
ಅಳದಾವ ụḷadaava
ಅಳೆಸಾಧಿಪು ụḷesaadhipu
ಅoದಾ ụndaa
ಅoಬಾಳ್ ụmbaaḷụ
ಅಂಕ ಕಾದುನಿ aṅka kaaduni
ಅಂಕದ ಬಾಕಿಯಾರ್ aṅkada baakiyaarụ
ಅಂಕದಾಯೆ aṅkadaaye
ಅಂಕಾಯನ aṅkaayana
ಅಂಕಿತ ಪಾಡುನಿ aṅkita paaḍuni
ಅಂಕುರಾರ್ಪಣೆ aṅkuraarpaṇϵ
ಅಂಗಡಿ ಚಾಮುಂಡಿ aṅgaḍi caamuṇḍi
ಅಂಗಡಿ ಪಾಡುನಿ aṅgaḍi paaḍuni
ಅಂಗಡಿ ಸಾಮಾನ್ aṅgaḍi saamaanụ
ಅಂಗಡಿಗಾರೆ aṅgaḍigaare
ಅಂಗಡಿದಾಯೆ aṅgaḍidaaye
ಅಂಗಣ ಸಿರಾವುನಿ aṅgaṇa siraavuni
ಅಂಗಣತ್ತಾಯೆ aṅgaṇattaaye
ಅಂಗತಾಪ aṅgataapa
ಅಂಗಲಪ್ಪುದಾಯೆ aṅgalappudaaye
ಅಂಗಲಾಪು aṅgalaapu
ಅಂಗಸಾಧನೆ aṅgasaadhanϵ
ಅಂಗಾ aṅgaa
ಅಂಗಾಂಗ aṅgaaṅga
ಅಂಗಾಂಗೊ aṅgaaṅgo
ಅಂಗಾಡಿ aṅgaaḍi
ಅಂಗಾತ aṅgaata
ಅಂಗಾತ್ನೆ aṅgaatnϵ
ಅಂಗಾತ್ನೆ aṅgaatnϵ
ಅಂಗಾಮೆ aṅgaame
ಅಂಗಾರಕ aṅgaaraka
ಅಂಗಾರಕವಾರ aṅgaarakavaara
ಅಂಗಾರಕೆ aṅgaarake
ಅಂಗಾರೆ aṅgaare
ಅಂಗಾರೆ ಪೇರರಿ aṅgaare peerari
ಅಂಗಾರೆ aṅgaarϵ
ಅಂಗಾರೆ aṅgaarϵ
ಅಂಗಾರ್ aṅgaarụ
ಅಂಗಿಂತಾಯ aṅgintaaya
ಅಂಗೀಕಾರ aṅgiikaara
ಅಂಗೀಕಾರ ಮಳ್ಪುನಿ aṅgiikaara maḷpuni
ಅಂಗುಷ್ಠ ಪ್ರಮಾಣತೆ aṅguṣṭha pramaaṇate
ಅಂಗುಸ್ತಾನ aṅgustaana
ಅಂಗುಸ್ತಾನಿ aṅgustaani
ಅಂಗೋಪಾಂಗ aṅgoopaaṅga
ಅಂಗ್ದಾಯೆ aṅgụdaaye
ಅಂಗ್ದಾಯೆ aṅgụdaaye
ಅಂಗ್ಸಾ aṅgụsaa
ಅಂಙ್ಙಣತ್ತಾಯೆ aṅṅaṇattaaye
ಅಂಚನಾ añcanaa
ಅಂಚನಾ ಇಂಚನಾ añcanaa iñcanaa
ಅಂಚಬನ್ನಾಯ añcabannaaya
ಅಂಚಲ್ದಾಯೆ añcalụdaaye
ಅಂಚಾಂಡ añcaaṇḍa
ಅಂಚಾದುಪ್ಪುನೆಡ್ದ್ añcaaduppuneḍdụ
ಅಂಚಾದ್ añcaadụ
ಅಂಚಾಪುನೆಡ್ದ್ añcaapuneḍdụ
ಅಂಚಾಯಿನೆಡ್ದಾವ añcaayineḍdaava
ಅಂಚಾಯಿನೆಡ್ದಾವರ añcaayineḍdaavara
ಅಂಚಾಯಿನೆಡ್ದ್ añcaayineḍdụ
ಅಂಚಿದಾಯೆ añcidaaye
ಅಂಜನ ಪಾಡುನಿ añjana paaḍuni
ಅಂಜನ ಪಾಡ್ದ್ ತೂಪುನಿ añjana paaḍụdụ tuupuni
ಅಂಜನಗಾರೆ añjanagaare
ಅಂಜನದಾಯೆ añjanadaaye
ಅಂಜಮಾನ añjamaana
ಅಂಜರ್ಬಾಳ್ añjarụbaaḷụ
ಅಂಜಾಲ್ ಮೀನ್ añjaalụ miinụ
ಅಂಜಿಕೆದಾಯೆ añjikedaaye
ಅಂಜುನಾಯೆ añjunaaye
ಅಂಟಾ aṇṭaa
ಅಂಟೆಕಾರ ಉರೆ aṇṭϵkaara urϵ
ಅಂಟೆಕಾರ್ aṇṭϵkaarụ
ಅಂಡಜಾತಿ aṇḍajaati
ಅಂಡಜಾಸನೆ aṇḍajaasane
ಅಂಡಜಾಹೊ aṇḍajaaho
ಅಂಡಿಣಾರ್ aṇḍiṇaarụ
ಅಂಡಿನಾರ್ aṇḍinaarụ
ಅಂಡಿಪಿನಾರ್ aṇḍipinaarụ
ಅಂಡಿಪುಣಾರ್ aṇḍipuṇaarụ
ಅಂಡಿಪುನಾರ್ aṇḍipunaarụ
ಅಂಡೆ ಪಾಜೆಯಿ aṇḍϵ paajeyi
ಅಂಡೆ ಪಾಜೊವು aṇḍϵ paajovu
ಅಂಡೆಕಾರ್ aṇḍekaarụ
ಅಂಡ್ಕಾಯಿ aṇḍkaayi
ಅಂತರ ಪಿಶಾಚಿ antara piśaaci
ಅಂತರಾಂತರ antaraantara
ಅಂತರಾಟ antaraaṭa
ಅಂತರಾತ್ಮ antaraatma
ಅಂತರಾತ್ಮೊ antaraatmo
ಅಂತರಿಯಾಮಿ antariyaami
ಅಂತರ್ ಕಮಾನ್ antarụ kamaanụ
ಅಂತರ್ಮಾಡ್ antarụmaaḍụ
ಅಂತಾರ antaara
ಅಂತಾರ antaara
ಅಂತಾರ ಬರ್ಪುನಿ antaara barpuni
ಅಂತಾಸ್ antaasụ
ಅಂತಿಲತ್ತಾಯ antilattaaya
ಅಂತಿಲ್ಲಾಯ antillaaya
ಅಂತ್ತಾವ antụtaava
ಅಂತ್ಯಕಾಲ antyakaala
ಅಂತ್ರಾಟ antraaṭa
ಅಂತ್ರಾಟೊ antraaṭo
ಅಂತ್ರಾಯ antraaya
ಅಂದಗಾರೆ andagaare
ಅಂದದ ಗಾಲಿ andada gaali
ಅಂದಸ್ಸ ಜಾಗ್ andassa jaagụ
ಅಂದಾ andaa
ಅಂದಾಂಟ andaaṇṭa
ಅಂದಾಂಡ andaaṇḍa
ಅಂದಾಜಿ andaaji
ಅಂದಾದುಪ್ಪುನಿ andaaduppuni
ಅಂದಾಪುನಿ andaapuni
ಅಂದಾಯ andaaya
ಅಂದಾಯಿ andaayi
ಅಂದಾಯಿ ಪಾತೆರ andaayi paatera
ಅಂದಾಯಿನ andaayina
ಅಂದಾಯಿನ andaayina
ಅಂದಾಯಿನ andaayina
ಅಂದಾಯೆ andaaye
ಅಂದಾವುಟಲ andaavuṭala
ಅಂದ್ಲಾಯಿಮರ andlaayimara
ಅಂಧಕಾರ andhakaara
ಅಂಧಕಾರೊ andhakaaro
ಅಂಧಾದರ್ಬಾರ್ andhaadarbaarụ
ಅಂಧಾದರ್ಬಾರ್ದಾಯೆ andhaadarbaarụdaaye
ಅಂಬಡೆ ಪಾಡುನಿ ambaḍϵ paaḍuni
ಅಂಬರ ಮಾರ್ಗ ambara maarga
ಅಂಬರಪ್ಪುದಾಯೆ ambarappudaaye
ಅಂಬರಾಂಬರ ambaraambara
ಅಂಬರಾಚರೆರ್ ambaraacarerụ
ಅಂಬಾ ambaa
ಅಂಬಾಕಿಲ್ ambaakilụ
ಅಂಬಾಡಿ ambaaḍi
ಅಂಬಾಡಿಯೆಲೆ ambaaḍiyelϵ
ಅಂಬಾರಿ ambaari
ಅಂಬಾರ್ ambaarụ
ಅಂಬಾವ ambaava
ಅಂಬಿ ಆಕುನಿ ambi aakuni

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: It still fails to retrieve any links, or display link texts when I added that statement.:

"The output:

List of links:
Search Language: Tulu Kannada English
Search Type: Exact Starting With Anywhere
    

Failed to retrieve results"

Do I have to switch to a different frame while trying to read the display text?

Comment: Yes you need to switch into another frame. Check the updated answer for full working code. Try it and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you access the [webpage](https://tuludictionary.in/dictionary/cgi-bin/web/frame.html) the options **Tulu** and **Starting With** is selected by default. So you need to select **Anywhere** and pass the text ***AA*** within the search box and click on <kbd>search</kbd>.

---

### Solution

To send a character sequence within the search box as the elements are within a [`<frame>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*`frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47771879/7429447) to switch to the initial frame.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- Switch to the [*default_content()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73186941/7429447)
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for the [*`frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47771879/7429447) to switch to the desired frame.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50159359/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):
- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://tuludictionary.in/dictionary/cgi-bin/web/frame.html")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"frame[name='search']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='SearchType'][value='Anywhere']"))).click()
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='search']").send_keys("AA")
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='sButton']").click()
  driver.switch_to.default_content()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"frame[name='resultside']")))
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table>tbody>tr>td")))])
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  ['Search Results\n-ಅoಬರಾ -ụmbaraa\n-ಅoಬೆರಾ -ụmberaa\n-ಅಪಾ -apaa\n-ಅರೆಗಾತ್ರ -aregaatra\n-ಅರೆಗಾಸ್ರ -aregaasra\n3 -ಆ -aa\n5 -ಆ -aa\n6 -ಆ -aa\n7 -ಆ -aa\n8 -ಆ -aa\n9 -ಆ -aa\n10 -ಆ -aa\n2 -ಆಂಡ -aaṇḍa\n-ಆಂತೆ -aantϵ\n-ಆಂದೆ -aandϵ\n-ಆಂದ್ -aandụ\n-ಆಟ -aaṭa\n3 -ಆಟ -aaṭa\n3 -ಆಟೊ -aaṭo\n-ಆಡ -aaḍa\n2 -ಆಡಿ -aaḍi\n2 -ಆಣ -aaṇa\n3 -ಆಣ -aaṇa\n1 -ಆಣಿ -aaṇi\n1 -ಆತೆಕೆ -aateke\n1 -ಆತೆಗೆ -aatege\n3 -ಆತ್ -aatụ\n5 -ಆತ್ -aatụ\n-ಆತ್ರ -aatra\n-ಆದಿಗೆ -aadigϵ\n1 -ಆದ್ -aadụ\n2 -ಆದ್ -aadụ\n1 -ಆನ -aana\n2 -ಆನ -aana\n1 -ಆನಿ -aani\n3 -ಆಯ್ -aayụ\n1 -ಆರ -aara\n2 -ಆರ -aara\n3 -ಆರ -aara\n11 -ಆರ್ -aarụ\n7 -ಆಲ್ -aalụ\n2 -ಆಳ -aaḷa\n2 -ಆಳ್ -aaḷụ\n3 -ಆಳ್ -aaḷụ\n1 -ಆವ -aava\n2 -ಆವ -aava\n-ಆವನೆ -aavane\n1 -ಆವರ -aavara\n1 -ಆವರೊ -aavaro\n1 -ಆವಾ -aavaa\n2 -ಆವು -aavu\n3 -ಆವು -aavu\n4 -ಆವು -aavu\n-ಆವ್ -aavụ\n1 -ಆಸ್ರ -aasra\n-ಇರ್ಸಾರ -irụsaara\n-ಉಂಬರಾ -umbaraa\n1 -ಎಟ್ಟಾ -eṭṭaa\n-ಎರಾ -eraa\n-ಒಂಟಾ -oṇṭaa\n-ಒಂತವಾ -ontavaa\n-ಒಲಿಯಾ -oliyaa\n1 -ಕಾ -kaa\n3 -ಕಾರ -kaara\n4 -ಕಾರ -kaara\n-ಕ್ಣಾ -kụṇaa\n-ಗಾರೆ -gaare\n4 -ಗಾರ್ -gaarụ\n3 -ಜಾರ್ -jaarụ\n-ಟಾವ -ṭaava\n-ಟ್ಪಾ -ṭụpaa\n-ಟ್ಪ್ಪಾ -ṭụppaa\n1 -ತವಾ -tavaa\n-ತಾ ತೊ -taa to\n-ತಾವ -taava\n2 -ತಿಮಾರ್ -timaarụ\n-ದಾರೆ -daare\n-ದಾರ್ -daarụ\n1 -ನಾ -naa\n2 -ನಾ -naa\n-ಪಾ -paa\n5 -ಪಾಯ -paaya\n3 -ಪಾಯಿ -paayi\n-ಪುಟ್ನಾಯೆ -puṭnaaye\n-ಪ್ಪಾಯಿ -ppaayi\n-ಮಾತಿಗ -maatiga\n4 -ಮಾರ್ -maarụ\n-ಮಾರ್ಕುಳು -maarkuḷu\n2 -ಮಾರ್ಗ -maarga\n-ಮಾಸ್ರ -maasra\n-ಮಾಸ್ರಿ -maasri\n2 -ರಾಕೆ -raakϵ\n3 -ವಾಶಿ -vaaśi\n4 -ವಾಸಿ -vaasi\n-ಷ್ಟ್ಪಾ -ṣṭụpaa\n6 -ಸಾರ -saara\n5 -ಸಾರಿ -saari\n-ಸೊಬಾನೆ -sobaanϵ\n.( poḍattarϵmaalϵ\n.. kebtaṇḍegụ haakuni\nಅಡ ಕಾರ್ ụḍa kaarụ\nಅಡೆಯಾಡ್ ụḍeyaaḍụ\nಅದನಾ ụdanaa\nಅದಾಪು ụdaapu\nಅಪಚಾರಿಪು ụpacaaripu\nಅಳದಾವ ụḷadaava\nಅಳೆಸಾಧಿಪು ụḷesaadhipu\nಅoದಾ ụndaa\nಅoಬಾಳ್ ụmbaaḷụ\nಅಂಕ ಕಾದುನಿ aṅka kaaduni\nಅಂಕದ ಬಾಕಿಯಾರ್ aṅkada baakiyaarụ\nಅಂಕದಾಯೆ aṅkadaaye\nಅಂಕಾಯನ aṅkaayana\nಅಂಕಿತ ಪಾಡುನಿ aṅkita paaḍuni\nಅಂಕುರಾರ್ಪಣೆ aṅkuraarpaṇϵ\nಅಂಗಡಿ ಚಾಮುಂಡಿ aṅgaḍi caamuṇḍi\nಅಂಗಡಿ ಪಾಡುನಿ aṅgaḍi paaḍuni\nಅಂಗಡಿ ಸಾಮಾನ್ aṅgaḍi saamaanụ\nಅಂಗಡಿಗಾರೆ aṅgaḍigaare\nಅಂಗಡಿದಾಯೆ aṅgaḍidaaye\nಅಂಗಣ ಸಿರಾವುನಿ aṅgaṇa siraavuni\nಅಂಗಣತ್ತಾಯೆ aṅgaṇattaaye\nಅಂಗತಾಪ aṅgataapa\nಅಂಗಲಪ್ಪುದಾಯೆ aṅgalappudaaye\nಅಂಗಲಾಪು aṅgalaapu\nಅಂಗಸಾಧನೆ aṅgasaadhanϵ\nಅಂಗಾ aṅgaa\nಅಂಗಾಂಗ aṅgaaṅga\nಅಂಗಾಂಗೊ aṅgaaṅgo\nಅಂಗಾಡಿ aṅgaaḍi\nಅಂಗಾತ aṅgaata\n1 ಅಂಗಾತ್ನೆ aṅgaatnϵ\n2 ಅಂಗಾತ್ನೆ aṅgaatnϵ\nಅಂಗಾಮೆ aṅgaame\nಅಂಗಾರಕ aṅgaaraka\nಅಂಗಾರಕವಾರ aṅgaarakavaara\nಅಂಗಾರಕೆ aṅgaarake\nಅಂಗಾರೆ aṅgaare\nಅಂಗಾರೆ ಪೇರರಿ aṅgaare peerari\n1 ಅಂಗಾರೆ aṅgaarϵ\n2 ಅಂಗಾರೆ aṅgaarϵ\nಅಂಗಾರ್ aṅgaarụ\nಅಂಗಿಂತಾಯ aṅgintaaya\nಅಂಗೀಕಾರ aṅgiikaara\nಅಂಗೀಕಾರ ಮಳ್ಪುನಿ aṅgiikaara maḷpuni\nಅಂಗುಷ್ಠ ಪ್ರಮಾಣತೆ aṅguṣṭha pramaaṇate\nಅಂಗುಸ್ತಾನ aṅgustaana\nಅಂಗುಸ್ತಾನಿ aṅgustaani\nಅಂಗೋಪಾಂಗ aṅgoopaaṅga\n1 ಅಂಗ್ದಾಯೆ aṅgụdaaye\n2 ಅಂಗ್ದಾಯೆ aṅgụdaaye\nಅಂಗ್ಸಾ aṅgụsaa\nಅಂಙ್ಙಣತ್ತಾಯೆ aṅṅaṇattaaye\nಅಂಚನಾ añcanaa\nಅಂಚನಾ ಇಂಚನಾ añcanaa iñcanaa\nಅಂಚಬನ್ನಾಯ añcabannaaya\nಅಂಚಲ್ದಾಯೆ añcalụdaaye\nಅಂಚಾಂಡ añcaaṇḍa\nಅಂಚಾದುಪ್ಪುನೆಡ್ದ್ añcaaduppuneḍdụ\nಅಂಚಾದ್ añcaadụ\nಅಂಚಾಪುನೆಡ್ದ್ añcaapuneḍdụ\nಅಂಚಾಯಿನೆಡ್ದಾವ añcaayineḍdaava\nಅಂಚಾಯಿನೆಡ್ದಾವರ añcaayineḍdaavara\nಅಂಚಾಯಿನೆಡ್ದ್ añcaayineḍdụ\nಅಂಚಿದಾಯೆ añcidaaye\nಅಂಜನ ಪಾಡುನಿ añjana paaḍuni\nಅಂಜನ ಪಾಡ್ದ್ ತೂಪುನಿ añjana paaḍụdụ tuupuni\nಅಂಜನಗಾರೆ añjanagaare\nಅಂಜನದಾಯೆ añjanadaaye\nಅಂಜಮಾನ añjamaana\nಅಂಜರ್ಬಾಳ್ añjarụbaaḷụ\nಅಂಜಾಲ್ ಮೀನ್ añjaalụ miinụ\nಅಂಜಿಕೆದಾಯೆ añjikedaaye\nಅಂಜುನಾಯೆ añjunaaye\nಅಂಟಾ aṇṭaa\nಅಂಟೆಕಾರ ಉರೆ aṇṭϵkaara urϵ\nಅಂಟೆಕಾರ್ aṇṭϵkaarụ\nಅಂಡಜಾತಿ aṇḍajaati\nಅಂಡಜಾಸನೆ aṇḍajaasane\nಅಂಡಜಾಹೊ aṇḍajaaho\nಅಂಡಿಣಾರ್ aṇḍiṇaarụ\nಅಂಡಿನಾರ್ aṇḍinaarụ\nಅಂಡಿಪಿನಾರ್ aṇḍipinaarụ\nಅಂಡಿಪುಣಾರ್ aṇḍipuṇaarụ\nಅಂಡಿಪುನಾರ್ aṇḍipunaarụ\nಅಂಡೆ ಪಾಜೆಯಿ aṇḍϵ paajeyi\nಅಂಡೆ ಪಾಜೊವು aṇḍϵ paajovu\nಅಂಡೆಕಾರ್ aṇḍekaarụ\nಅಂಡ್ಕಾಯಿ aṇḍkaayi\nಅಂತರ ಪಿಶಾಚಿ antara piśaaci\nಅಂತರಾಂತರ antaraantara\nಅಂತರಾಟ antaraaṭa\nಅಂತರಾತ್ಮ antaraatma\nಅಂತರಾತ್ಮೊ antaraatmo\nಅಂತರಿಯಾಮಿ antariyaami\nಅಂತರ್ ಕಮಾನ್ antarụ kamaanụ\nಅಂತರ್ಮಾಡ್ antarụmaaḍụ\n1 ಅಂತಾರ antaara\n2 ಅಂತಾರ antaara\nಅಂತಾರ ಬರ್ಪುನಿ antaara barpuni\nಅಂತಾಸ್ antaasụ\nಅಂತಿಲತ್ತಾಯ antilattaaya\nಅಂತಿಲ್ಲಾಯ antillaaya\nಅಂತ್ತಾವ antụtaava\nಅಂತ್ಯಕಾಲ antyakaala\nಅಂತ್ರಾಟ antraaṭa\nಅಂತ್ರಾಟೊ antraaṭo\nಅಂತ್ರಾಯ antraaya\nಅಂದಗಾರೆ andagaare\nಅಂದದ ಗಾಲಿ andada gaali\nಅಂದಸ್ಸ ಜಾಗ್ andassa jaagụ\nಅಂದಾ andaa\nಅಂದಾಂಟ andaaṇṭa\nಅಂದಾಂಡ andaaṇḍa\nಅಂದಾಜಿ andaaji\nಅಂದಾದುಪ್ಪುನಿ andaaduppuni\nಅಂದಾಪುನಿ andaapuni\nಅಂದಾಯ andaaya\nಅಂದಾಯಿ andaayi\nಅಂದಾಯಿ ಪಾತೆರ andaayi paatera\nಅಂದಾಯಿನ andaayina\n1 ಅಂದಾಯಿನ andaayina\n2 ಅಂದಾಯಿನ andaayina\nಅಂದಾಯೆ andaaye\nಅಂದಾವುಟಲ andaavuṭala\nಅಂದ್ಲಾಯಿಮರ andlaayimara\nಅಂಧಕಾರ andhakaara\nಅಂಧಕಾರೊ andhakaaro\nಅಂಧಾದರ್ಬಾರ್ andhaadarbaarụ\nಅಂಧಾದರ್ಬಾರ್ದಾಯೆ andhaadarbaarụdaaye\nಅಂಬಡೆ ಪಾಡುನಿ ambaḍϵ paaḍuni\nಅಂಬರ ಮಾರ್ಗ ambara maarga\nಅಂಬರಪ್ಪುದಾಯೆ ambarappudaaye\nಅಂಬರಾಂಬರ ambaraambara\nಅಂಬರಾಚರೆರ್ ambaraacarerụ\nಅಂಬಾ ambaa\nಅಂಬಾಕಿಲ್ ambaakilụ\nಅಂಬಾಡಿ ambaaḍi\nಅಂಬಾಡಿಯೆಲೆ ambaaḍiyelϵ\nಅಂಬಾರಿ ambaari\nಅಂಬಾರ್ ambaarụ\nಅಂಬಾವ ambaava\nಅಂಬಿ ಆಕುನಿ ambi aakuni']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: I got the following error while trying to display the output links' text. Also, I wanted to select the 'Tulu' and 'Anywhere' radio buttons though.

"line 13: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0c86' in position 21: character maps to <undefined>"

Also btw, try searching something else like 'JJJ', I wanted to separately handle if I received 'No results found'.

Comment: @MilindChakraborty _UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character_: is pure pythonic error. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52935424/7429447), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63458422/7429447) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66189999/7429447) discussions.

Comment: @MilindChakraborty Checkout the updated answer to select the 'Tulu' and 'Anywhere' radio buttons and let me know the status.

Comment: It works, also I fixed the Unicode error. Thank you.